# mysql : group by doesn't work

Tags: mysql

This is my query

```
SELECT r.stars
FROM ratingstar r
INNER JOIN proposals p ON p.jobid = r.jobid
INNER JOIN us_signup u ON u.id = p.userid
WHERE r.type =  'user'
AND u.id =  '54'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

returns

stars=[2,3,4]

but I want it to return count=3 and stars=9

I tried

```
SELECT count(*), count(r.stars)
FROM ratingstar r
INNER JOIN proposals p ON p.jobid = r.jobid
INNER JOIN us_signup u ON u.id = p.userid
WHERE r.type =  'user'
AND u.id =  '54'
GROUP BY r.stars
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but didn't give me the expected result

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `COUNT` and `SUM` (without `GROUP BY`) if you just want two values, e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(r.stars) AS 'count', SUM(r.stars) AS 'stars'
FROM ratingstar r
INNER JOIN proposals p ON p.jobid = r.jobid
INNER JOIN us_signup u ON u.id = p.userid
WHERE r.type =  'user'
AND u.id =  '54';
```

If you want the count of distinct values, you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT r.stars)`